# Giving distinctive color for each curve in my plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I was wondering if I can give a distinctive color/marker for each curve in my plot, my plot has 20 different curves and it is hard to differentiate between the curves because some of them have the same colors. Is there a way to control the color for each curve? or give different marker for each curve then they become distinctive? 
here is my plotting code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
for cluster_index in [0,1,2]:
    plt.subplot(3,1,cluster_index + 1)

    for index, row in data1.iterrows():
        if row.iloc[-1] == cluster_index:
            plt.plot(row.iloc[1:-1] ,marker='v', alpha=1)

        plt.legend(loc="right")

    plt.plot(kmeans.cluster_centers_[cluster_index], color='k' ,marker='o', alpha=1)
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.tick_params(axis = 'x', which = 'major', labelsize = 8)  
    plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
    plt.ylabel('Consumption in Winter-2019')
    plt.title(f'Cluster {cluster_index}', fontsize=20)


plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

and here is a photo for the specific output that I wanna edit the color of the curves in it:
[image]

The output for the second cluster has 20 curves and I want to give 20 different marker or controlling the color somehow to make it more visually appear. Please any help

Comment: Change the `color=` and `marker=` arguments of `plt.plot` on each iteration of the loop?

Comment: u mean I should assign the marker/color to a variable?